# How can you search Unicode codepoints by name in Perl6?

Tags: unicode, raku

If you already know the name of the codepoint, such as `GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI`, you can obtain the character using `\c`. There is an equivalent NQP in `getunicode`. However, is there a way of looking up all GREEK SMALL LETTER, for instance? 
I have tried to find out where those names are stored, but I haven't found them in NQP, Rakudo or MoarVM source. Any idea?

Comment: [src/strings/unicode_db.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/master/src/strings/unicode_db.c) in the MoarVM repository (> 1 MB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just go through all of Unicode codepoints, and test them

```perl6
(0..0x10FFFF).grep: *.uniname.starts-with('GREEK SMALL LETTER ');
```

You might want to get the values that are Greek and lowercase instead of only the ones that have `GREEK SMALL LETTER` in their name.

```perl6
(0..0x10FFFF).grep: {
  .uniprop('Script') eq 'Greek'
  and
  .uniprop('Lowercase')
}
```